# How to avoid spark from reading files whose path don't exist in s3

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have some s3 files as
`s3://test-shivi/blah1/blah1.parquet`,
`s3://test-shivi/blah2/blah2.parquet`,
`s3://test-shivi/blah3/NONE`

Now I want to load all the parquet via spark such as

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://test-shivi/*.*.parquet", schema=spark_schema)
```

But as `blah3` doesn't have a matching file, I am getting this error.

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: s3:
```

How can I safeguard/ skip those dirs that don't have any matching files?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that your path / wildcard pattern is wrong. Use this instead:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://test-shivi/*/*.parquet", schema=spark_schema)
```

If `blah3` doesn't contain a parquet file, it won't match the pattern. That won't cause any issue.

But be careful with leading slashes: `s3a:///` is wrong, it has to be `s3a://{bucket}/`.